# laravel undefined variable error in foreach

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

this is my controller function

```
public function products() {

    return view('products', array('page' => 'products'));
}
```

this is view

`@foreach ($products as $product)`

this is route

`Route::get('products','FrontController@products');`

this is error

> Undefined variable: products (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OSM\resources\views\products.blade.php)

Comment: help me to find an error please

Comment: you have set the name of your variable to page with a value of products do: `return view('products',compact('products'));` then run your foreach

Comment: you also need to have a collection or variable called products like: `$products = Product::orderBy('price','asc')->get();`

Comment: it did not solve my problem

Comment: have one more error (i am new in laravel)                                                            FatalErrorException in FrontController.php line 19:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Product' not found

Comment: ok thanxxx alot its working now :)

Comment: No problem kindly mark my comment as useful

Answer (score 1):

The way you are passing the data to view, is making a variable named `$page` with the value of `"products"`.

Inside your controller, you will need to grab the products data you want passed to the foreach loop and save it to a variable. Assuming that you already have an [Eloquent model](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) called 'Product', you could call `$products = Product::all();` and this would return a Collection of every Product. Then you can pass that to your views using

- `view('products')->withProducts($products)`
- `view('products')->with('products', $products)`;
- `view('products', ['products' => $products]);`

There are other methods as well, for example using [compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) if you have a variable named `$products` and `$page` like

```
view('products', compact('products', 'page'));
```

`compact`basically creates an array using with variable names as keys and variable values as the corresponding values.